# Instant return to initial state after Angular2 Animate based animation to be able to run the animation several times

Tags: animation, angular

I'm trying to accomplish a simple Angular2 animation using the Animate modules.

Here is what I managed to do so far: https://plnkr.co/edit/o0ukvWEB4THB0EQmv0Zu

Everything is as I'm expecting it, the red cross progressively disappears in a motion to the top.

My problem is that I want to be able to do the same animation as many times as I want.

I used the `onComplete` method with a callback that resets the styles to the initial state. The only problem I have is that instead of returning instantly to it's initial state the object "annimates back". So I have two animations instead of only one.

I think I'm misunderstanding some of the concepts of the Angular2 Animate modules or maybe simply lacking the required CSS skills.

Any help appreciated.

Here is my code so far:

```ts
//our root app component
import {Component, Directive, ElementRef} from 'angular2/core';
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {AnimationBuilder} from 'angular2/src/animate/animation_builder';
import Subject from '@reactivex/rxjs/dist/cjs/Subject';

@Directive({
  selector : '[animate-box]',
  host : {
    '[style.background-color]' : "'transparent'"
  },
  exportAs : 'ab'
})
class AnimateBox {
    animation: Animation;
    a:Animation;
    
    cb: Function = () => {
        console.log("animation finished");
        console.dir(this.a);
        this.a.applyStyles({top: '-20px', opacity: '100' });
    };

    constructor(private _ab: AnimationBuilder, private _e: ElementRef) {
      
    }
  
  
  toggle(isVisible: boolean = false) {
    this.animation = this._ab.css();
    this.animation
      .setDuration(1000);
    
    this.animation.addAnimationClass("test-animation-class");
        
    this.animation.setFromStyles(
                {
                    top: '-20px', 
                    opacity: '100',  
                })
            .setToStyles(
                {
                    opacity: '0',  
                    top: '-120px'
                });
            
    this.a = this.animation.start(this._e.nativeElement);
        
    this.a.onComplete(this.cb);
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <span class="vote"><span animate-box #box="ab" class="test-vote"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></span>1</span>
    <button data-tooltip="I’m the tooltip text." (click)="box.toggle(visible = !visible)">Animate</button>
  `,
  directives : [AnimateBox]
})
export class App {
  visible = true;
}

bootstrap(App).catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**update**

I created just two animations for forward and backwards and start one run on the end of the onComplete callback of the previous animation.

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/f9X2UfWdExhCh6oAX9hc?p=preview)

```ts
class AnimateBox {
    //animation: Animation;
    //a:Animation;

    constructor(private _ab: AnimationBuilder, private _e: ElementRef) {}

  createAnimation:Function = (forward:boolean, count:number):Animation => {
    animation = this._ab.css();
    animation.setDuration(1000);
      animation.addAnimationClass("test-animation-class");
      if(forward) {
      animation.setFromStyles({
            top: '-20px', 
            opacity: '100',  
        })
        .setToStyles({
            top: '-120px'
            opacity: '0',  
        });
      } else {
      animation.setFromStyles({
            top: '-120px', 
            opacity: '0',  
        })
        .setToStyles({
            opacity: '100',  
            top: '-20px'
        });
      }

      a = animation.start(this._e.nativeElement);
      console.log(a);
      a.onComplete(() => { this.onComplete(forward, count);});
  };

    onComplete:Function = (forward:boolean, count:number) => {
        console.log("animation finished");
        //console.dir(this.a);
        //animation.applyStyles({top: '-20px', opacity: '100' });
        if(count) {
          a = this.createAnimation(!forward, --count);
          console.log('a ' + a);
        }
    };

    toggle:Function =(isVisible: boolean = false) => {
    this.createAnimation(true,10);
  };
}
```

**original**

When you set

```ts
cb: Function = () => {
    console.log("animation finished");
    console.dir(this.a);
    // this.a.applyStyles({top: '-20px', opacity: '100' });
};
```

`top` is animated back. Just comment the line out and it stops after moving up.

`setFromStyles()` is also redundant because the element has that style already.

Comment: This answer misses my main point "run the animation several times". This basically disables the onComplete method. It moves the image to the top and the image stays there. My point is to bring the image back instantly at the end of the animation in order to have it ready for another animation if the animate button is pressed again.

Comment: I see, wasn't too obvious from the title of your question. I'll have another look later.

Comment: You are right, I updated the title. This is also why I use the setFromStyles and setToStyles methods. My idea is to have the main class with the top and opacity at the value where the component appears on initial page load, use the element styles to run the animation and remove the styles when the animation is finished in the onComplete callback. This is basically what my code does already. The only real problem is that when I change the styles in the callback the state change is also animated. I want it to instantly appear at its initial position without animation.

Comment: Ok! This works. It is a generic answer that allows to create what I want. Thanks

Comment: Great! Animation is a very basic implementation and only experimental currently. It will be improved substantially when Angulars core parts are more stable.